# Rails extract values with join associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, activerecord

I have a rails join table between 2 models `superhero` and `superpower`. Now I have 3 different `superpower id` and I want all the `superheroes` which have all the selected `superpowers`

To do that I'm trying to do the following:

```
matches = Superhero.all
matches = matches.joins(:superpowers).where('superpowers.id = ?', 17).where('superpowers.id = ?', 12).where('superpowers.id = ?', 6)
```

But this gives me an empty object even though I have `superheroes` which have all the given `superpowers` in my join table

The query generated from the above is:

```
SELECT "superheroes".* FROM "superheroes" INNER JOIN "superheroes_superpowers" ON "superheroes_superpowers"."superhero_id" = "superheroes"."id" INNER JOIN "superpowers" ON "superpowers"."id" = "superheroes_superpowers"."superpower_id" WHERE (superpowers.id = 17) AND (superpowers.id = 17) AND (superpowers.id = 12) AND (superpowers.id = 6)
```

So weirdly it tries to check for the `superpower` with id 17 twice (but it shouldn't affect the result I think) and the rest of the query seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using an in clause

```
superpowers_ids = [17,12,6]
matches = Superhero.all
matches = matches.joins(:superpowers).where('superpowers.id in (?)', superpowers_ids)
```

Comment: sould be the same  ..  i have used  binding thinking  you need  some particular bind  ..

Comment: Yes it works! I made a mistake while doing this. Only issue is that it returns the same record multiple times

Comment: @awefwa I think you can append it with `.uniq` to get a single instance

Answer (score 0):

```
Superhero.joins(:superpowers).where(superpowers:  { id: [17,12,6] } )
```

---

This gives the following SQL query (formatted for readibility):

```
SELECT "superheros".* 
FROM "superheros" 
INNER JOIN "superhero_superpowers" ON "superhero_superpowers"."superhero_id" = "superheros"."id" 
INNER JOIN "superpowers" ON "superpowers"."id" = "superhero_superpowers"."superpower_id" 
WHERE "superpowers"."id" IN (17, 12, 6)
```

Comment: Actually this gives me an error that `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column superheroes.superpower_id does not exist`

Comment: You're right it should be `Superhero.joins(:superpowers).where(superpowers:  { id: [17,12,6] } )`